# Apache POI reading cell (12:35:00 PM) time value return 31-Dec-1899

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

am trying to read a xlsx file in java
seem to be working fine till i got to the time cell it prints an ood date
and this doing it for all of the time values 
how do i get the really cell to string
all so if theres a better way to do this plz let me know thx

code:

```
FileInputStream fileIn = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        Workbook wb = null;
        try
        {
            fileIn = new FileInputStream(filename);
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn);
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                System.out.println(wb.getNumberOfSheets());
            Iterator<Row> r=sheet.rowIterator();
            while(r.hasNext())
            {
               Row getrow=r.next();
               Iterator<Cell> c=getrow.cellIterator();
               while(c.hasNext())
               {
                   Cell getcell=c.next();
                   System.out.print(getcell.toString()+" @ ");

               }
                System.out.println("");
            }
```

hope this works first time i shareing file like this with dropbox
xlsx file :
[THE FILE IN DROPBOX](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8t3hhvhxfgtv2u/t.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

[Reading time values from spreadsheet using poi api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710888/reading-time-values-from-spreadsheet-using-poi-api)
this post gave me a hint and explain the problem

```
//get date
        Date date = poiCell.getDateCellValue();

        //set up formatters that will be used below
        SimpleDateFormat formatTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
 if(getcell.toString().contains("31-Dec-1899")){
                      // System.out.println(getcell.getDateCellValue());
                       String timeStamp =formatTime.format(getcell.getDateCellValue());
```

il prob change it to if at X index do use the format  hope it helps others